# c#: What happens exactly when I initialize an array of bools like this

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization, boolean

Im getting into C# and im a little bit confused [about an example of the resource im learning from.](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson02) Its about the declaration and initialisation of a bool array, id like to know what happens at what point in the code:

```
    bool[][] myBools = new bool[2][];
    myBools[0] = new bool[2];
    myBools[1] = new bool[1];

    myBools[0][0] = true;
    //myBools[0][1] = false;
    myBools[1][0] = true;
    Console.WriteLine("myBools[0][0]: {0}, myBools[1][0]: {1}", myBools[0][0], myBools[1][0]);
```

I declare a 2 dimensional bool array of unknown size - in the same line I initialize the array of array with 2 arrays of booleans.

What do I have at that moment in the array? C# doesnt allow to read out the values. (I think I now have an array_main with 2 members containing uninitialized! bool arrays_members is this correct? So an array of len 2 containing 2 members that are bool arrays of unkown lenght containing NULL?)

In line 2 and 3 I initialize the array_members with boolean arrays, the first member with lenght 2 and the second one with lenght 1. Is this correct?

After that its simple, C like.

I can work with the logic, but id like to know whats going on behind the scenes.

Comment: No.  The 2nd array is a pointer to another area of memory.  So the 2nd array is a null address pointer.  I would use instead of an array a List<List<Boolean>> which will be easier to add values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I declare a 2 dimensional bool array of unknown size

Well, you declare an array of arrays. It's not a "real" multi-dimensional array - that would be `bool[,] myBools`. It's worth understanding the difference between *jagged arrays* (an array where the element type is another array type) and rectangular arrays (where there's a single array object, but with multiple dimensions).

> What do I have at that moment in the array?

You have two null references. This is easy to see:

```
bool[][] myBools = new bool[2][];
bool[] array = myBools[0];
Console.WriteLine(array == null); // true
```

Basically, you're just creating an array where the element type is a reference type. Think of it as if you had a class called `BoolArray`, and you created:

```
BoolArray[] myBools = new BoolArray[2];
```

Then you'd expect both elements to have a value of null, because that's the default for all reference types, right? Well, that's exactly what you've got... it's just that the array type is `bool[]` rather than a simple class.

> In line 2 and 3 I initialize the array_members with boolean arrays, the first member with length 2 and the second one with length 1. Is this correct?

Yes, exactly.